# How to track java method calls and get alerts in Dynatrace?

Tags: microservices, distributed-computing, trace, dynatrace

I have a code similar to the one below. Every-time a DBLock appears, I want to get an alert in Dynatrace creating a problem so that I can see it on the dashboard and possibly get an email notification also. The DB lock would appear if the update count is greater than 1.

```
 private int removeDBLock(DataSource dataSource) {
   
    int updateCount = 0;
    final Timestamp lastAllowedDBLockTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - (5 * 60 * 1000));
    final String query = format(RELEASE_DB_CHANGELOCK, lastAllowedDBLockTime.toString());
    try (Statement stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement()) {
        updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if(updateCount>0){
            log.error("Stale DB Lock found. Locks Removed Count is {} .",updateCount);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error while trying to find and remove Db Change Lock. ",e);
    }
    return updateCount;
}
```

I tried using the event API to trigger an event on my host mentioned here and was successful in raising a problem alert on my dashboard.

https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/events/post-event/?request-parameters%3C-%3Ejson-model=json-model

but this would mean injecting an api call in my code just for monitoring, any may lead to more external dependencies and hence more chance of failure.

I also tried creating a custom service detection by adding the class containing this method and the method itself in the custom service. But I do not know how I can link this to an alert or a event that creates a problem on the dashboard.

Are there any best practices or solutions on how I can do this in Dynatrace. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: If you have a log collector it would be a lot easier to fetch this issue as you are logging the particular issue. I am not sure if there is a clean way of informing dynatrace with your particular code but I know from my previous experience that dynatrace itself already monitor the db locks. Give it a try it may help you without doing anything extra. Use this link to see how to check it https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/198157/how-to-identify-db-locks-on-dynatrace.html

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Custom Services for Java](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/easily-configure-detection-environments-custom-application-services/) which will cause invocations of the method to be monitored in more detail.

Maybe you can extract a method which actually throws the exception and the outer method which handles it. Then it should be possible to alert on the exception.

There are also some more ways to configure the service via settings, i.e. raise an error based on a return value directly.

See also documentation:

- https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/transactions-and-services/configuration/define-custom-services/
- https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/application-software/java/configuration-and-analysis/define-custom-java-services/